# Normal Subgroups and Isomorphisms Help

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Prove or give a counterexample: If $H, K$ are normal subgroups to $G$ and $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G/K$, then $H$ is isomorphic to $K$.

proof:
Let $G$ be the Klein-4 Group ($V$), $H = \langle a\rangle$, and $K = \langle b\rangle$. $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups to $G$ since $G$ is abelian.
Then $|G/H| = |V/\langle a\rangle| = 4/2 = 2$ and $|G/K| = |V/\langle b\rangle| = 4/2 = 2$. So $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G/K$.
But $H$ is not isomorphic to $K$ since $a$ does not equal $b$.

Comment: Looks like your math got cut off. Also, equal order does not imply isomorphic (although it does when the order is 2).

Comment: Just because two groups are unequal does not mean they are not isomorphic. (If it did, we wouldn't even need the concept of isomorphism, since equality would suffice.) In fact, $\langle a\rangle\cong C_2\cong\langle b\rangle$ in the Klein four-group.

Comment: "$\langle a\rangle$ is not isomorphic to $\langle b\rangle$ because $a\ne b$" - this is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a countably infinite product of copies of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, and take $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2$. Another example is that $S^1/\langle e^{2\pi i/n}\rangle \simeq S^1$ for any $n$.